# 'Wrong' profile ID being returned from Google Analytics python API

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am attempting to set up some code to analyze data from my Google Analytics account via the python API but have run into a problem with the profile_id that is being returned.

I am following the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py). What I have done so far is to create I created a service account which provided an address of the form `<projectId>-<uniqueId>@developer.gserviceaccount.com` - this was then added to the Google Analytics account that I want to work with.

I then followed the tutorial, and the code below succeeds and returns a profile ID. The problem is that this profile ID isn't the same one that I can find by going to the dashboard for my Google Analytics account and looking by hand.

If I use the string that is returned from the function below to query the API then I get just empty results (ie the code succeeded in querying some metric like users in the past 7 days, but it just returns that the answer is zero).

If instead I just hard code the string I find on the dashboard then everything works fine and the correct results are returned. This obviously isn't very satisfying though and I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong by trying to extract the profile ID via the python code.

```
accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

if accounts.get('items'):
  firstAccountId = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')
  webproperties = service.management().webproperties().list(
    accountId=firstAccountId).execute()

  if webproperties.get('items'):
    firstWebpropertyId = webproperties.get('items')[0].get('id')
    profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
      accountId=firstAccountId,
      webPropertyId=firstWebpropertyId).execute()

    if profiles.get('items'):
      return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

return None
```

Comment: Extremely wild guess (since I use the same code and it's working for me, so I don't think you are doing anything wrong there), but maybe you have deleted a view (profile) and it's still in the rubbish bin ? Might be that the API is not aware of the rubbish bin, which is a relatively new feature, and picks the deleted view as the first profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this problem looking for the solution, it turns out that in my case there had been several profiles created and attached to the account I was querying. By taking the first profile I was picking up a now redundant profile.